# Как лучше построить две связанных таблицы в PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Я первый раз использую Postgres(и вообще sql бд), и многого еще не понимаю, буду рад любой помощи

Мне нужно создать бэк используя `nestjs` и `typeorm` для так скажем простейшей библиотеки(имеется в виду книжной): есть пользователи и если у них есть подписка, то можно брать до 5 книг в пользование. Если подписки нету, то соответственно вообще нельзя. Так же нужны методы для добавления книги в бд, для ее добавления к пользователю и для "ее возвращения". Я сделал 2 таблицы, одну с пользователями, другую с книгами. Как лучше реализовать наличие этих книг у пользователя? Просто массивом из айдишников этих книг или массивом из объектов самих книг или еще какие-то варианты есть лучше?

Так же можете написать в тг, будет немного поудобнее) @tediouscode

Comment: Читайте теорию по терминам "анализ предметной области для проектирования базы данных" и "построение ER-диаграммы (ER-модели)". Проектировать структуру на основании некоего мистического озарения - бессмысленно, а любые ошибки в проектировании потом аукаются большими проблемами. Какая будет потом использоваться СУБД - это вообще дело десятое.

Comment: Напрашивается третья таблица "книги у пользователя". в которой id кользователя, id книги и возможно какие нибудь дополнительные данные, типа когда взял, когда вернуть и т.п., если необходимы. См. связь "многие ко многим"

Answer (score 0):

В твоём случае один пользователь может иметь несколько книг - это отношение один-ко-многим. В сущностях ты можешь настроить их отношение

```
@Entity()
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Book, (book) => book.owner)
  book: Book;
}


@Entity()
class Book {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.book)
  owner: User;
}
```

Вот документация на эту тему - https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md